# How to Create item templates for ASP.NET Core 2.1

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1, visual-studio-templates

I have ran into [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-item-templates?view=vs-2017) and tried to do it for my solution except it only works in class libraries and not web projects. how can I achieve this in web project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally after countless hours I was able to do it after adding `<TemplateGroupID>AspNetCore</TemplateGroupID>` to the generated .vstemplate inside`<TemplateData></TemplateData>`